# SQL, как сгруппировать данные в столбце и вывести новые столбцы для каждой группы с его данными?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, plsql

Имеется таблица table [image: Картинка1]

с помощью команд SELECT надо вывести как на картинке2
[image: Картинка2]

Comment: Какая логика построения? Почему в строке несколько колонок с `type_id` ?

Comment: Просто есть таблица его надо вывести как на второй картинке с помощью SELECT. Тут type_id не первичный ключ, а просто колонка, и может принимать non-unique параметры. Получается делят по type_id, если type_id другой тогда новую колонку добавляет

Comment: Похоже на то, что так как на картинке универсально выводить не получится или мне не знаком способ это сделать. Вы уверены,что правильно нарисовали картинку? В названии вопроса Вы написали, что вывести строки как столбцы. То что вы нарисовали, это другое

Comment: А если еще один type_id будет, я так понимаю вы хотите колонки и для него ? ... Это невозможно. В SQL запросе количество колонок должно быть оговорено заранее. Такие трансформации следует выполнять на клиенте. Т.е. конкретно побить на 3 группы по горизонтали не особая проблема, но групп будет именно 3 и значения 55, 56, 57 будут жестко зашиты в запрос

Comment: Извиняюсь если неправильно задал вопрос! Ну вообщем на картинке думаю понятно!)) Групп будет только три! Просто надо сформировать и вывести в таком виде!

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (
  select type_id, col_1, col_2,
         row_number() over(partition by type_id order by col_1) as grp
    from T
)
pivot(
  max(type_id) as type_id, max(col_1) as col_1, max(col_2) as col_2
   for(type_id) in(55, 56, 57)
)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Правильно)))